# How can I get phone info such as the language of the phone and phone operator in Corona?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to retrieve the info form the phones that which operator it uses and what's the language of phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the language by using

```
system.getPreference( "ui", "language" )
```

have a read here
http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/systemgetpreference

And I'm pretty sure that there is no way (yet) to retrieve operator info.